# At weekends they prefer to stay home and visit some friends

Tags: verbs, semantics

I am wondering how this sentence is to be paraphrased:

> At weekends they prefer to stay home and visit some friends.

I am not sure which ones are close to the original:

1. They like to remain in their house at weekends and they also like to go and see their friends.
2. They like to remain in their house at weekends and to go and see their friends.
3. They like to remain in their house for a while at weekends and then go and see their friends.
4. They go and see their friends on weekdays but would rather remain in their house at weekends.
5. They generally go and see their friends but would rather remain in their house at weekends.
6. They like to remain in their house at weekends or else to go and see their friends.

Comment: I'm wondering where people say "_at_ weekends" in stead of "_on_ weekends". Does your source mention that, just for curiosity's sake?

Comment: @Conrado - We British say "at weekends/the weekend".

Comment: I think that the original sentence is somewhat confusing and contradictory, which leads to ambiguous paraphrasals.

Comment: Lacking any context for the sentence, I would understand it to mean "At weekends, they like to remain in their home district and visit friends who live nearby". I don't find 'some' very natural.

Comment: @Heartspring How about this one: 
'At weekends they prefer to stay home and to visit friends' ?

Comment: @KateBunting Sure enough it shows up online... I can't remember ever hearing it among the Americans where I was born.

Comment: @Conrado: [*We use **at** in Britain!*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=home+at+weekends%2Chome+on+weekends&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) But that usage chart doesn't tell the whole story, because [*we usually use singular **the weekend,** anyway.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=home+at+the+weekend%2Chome+on+the+weekend&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) But the question is pointless without context - and if there *was* context, the exact meaning would probably be obvious.

Comment: Why is this closed? The question is completely clear and can be answered without resorting to opinion.

Comment: stay home **can mean** ***not travel***.

Answer (score 4):

The structure of the sentence definitely means that they like to do two things on a weekend - 1) stay home and 2) visit friends. This seems contradictory, as you can't stay in your house and also go to visit friends.

However "stay home" doesn't always mean "stay in your house". It may mean "stay in your town" or "stay in your home area", if the context is travel. For example:

> Janet and John like to travel to different cities during the week. At weekends they prefer to stay home and visit some friends.

This means they stay in their home city, not necessarily in their actual home, and visit friends in that city. This is probably what is meant, but context would make it clearer.

None of the sentences you describe as paraphrases convey this properly.

1. Not really. The original sentence clearly means they visit friends on the weekend
2. Again no, for the same reason.
3. Possibly. "Then" would be incorrect as no order is implied by the original sentence. This sentence does not make it clear that "visiting friends" is preferred on the weekends, which the original does.
4. Definitely not. The original sentence is definitely talking about what they prefer on weekends.
5. Definitely not, for the same reason.
6. Possibly. The use of "and" generally means they prefer to do both, not one or the other.

**TLDR: "Stay home" doesn't necessarily mean "stay in your house". Accepting this, the sentence clearly means they do both "staying home" and "visiting friends" at weekends.**

Comment: Would your answer be different if "to" was placed in the original sentence? I mean, "At weekends they prefer to stay home and to visit some friends"?

Comment: No, no difference at all.

Comment: Wouldn't "At weekends they prefer to stay home and to visit some friends" mean something close to "At weekends they prefer either to stay home or to visit some friends"?

Comment: No. The word "and" is explicitly used, and means something different from "or". In any case the "to" applies across both phrases implicitly in the original sentence.

Comment: If  you stay home (not travel) you can still visit friends...it works fine.

Comment: "And" can be used to indicate two alternatives: "At weekends they prefer to play football and golf" is perfectly cromulent and doesn't mean they play both at the same time.